# How to prevent listArray from populating multiple times?

Tags: android, listview

I have a spinner populated from an API call.
At first loading of fragment, the list is correctly populated, with differents items, one for row.
After a submit (I need a submit in this fragment) the List is re-populated several times.

This is the **onCreate** method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mItemSubscriptionList = new ArrayList<>();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

And this is the method that populate the array list

```
private void loadItemSubscription() {

        ApiMapper mapper = new ApiMapper();
        mapper.getBalance(new ApiMapper.VolleyCallback<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray balance) {

               if (balance != null) {

                   Log.d(LOGTAG , balance.toString());

                   mItemSubscriptionList.clear();

                   for (int i = 0; i < balance.length(); i++) {

                       Log.d(LOGTAG , "Popolo lo spinner "+i);
                       try {

                           JSONObject obj = balance.getJSONObject(i);

                           String quantity = obj.getString("balance");

                           quantity = quantity.replace(".00","");

                               int id_item = obj.getInt("id_item");
                               String item = obj.getString("item");

                                item = item + ' '+'('+quantity+')';

                               Log.d(LOGTAG , quantity);
                               Log.d(LOGTAG , item);

                               ModelItemSubscription modelItemSubscription = new ModelItemSubscription();

                               modelItemSubscription.setMItemId(id_item);
                               modelItemSubscription.setMItemName(item);
                               modelItemSubscription.setMItemQuantity(quantity);

                               mItemSubscriptionList.add(modelItemSubscription);

                               mBaseApp.setItemSubscription(modelItemSubscription);


                           mLoadingDialog.dismiss();


                       } catch (JSONException e) {

                           e.printStackTrace();

                       }

                   }



                }

                mItemSubscriptionList = mBaseApp.getItemSubscription();

                if ( mItemSubscriptionList!=null ) {

                    renderSpinnerItemSubscription(mItemSubscriptionList);

                }

            }
        }, mToken, mIdMemberCard, mIdCampaign);

    }
```

In real scenario, I have 4 items to populate. The Log ***"Popolo lo spinner"*** **is printed exactly 4 times, but this is the ugly finaly result.**

[image]

Instead this is the right behaviour after the first loading (only 1 item for type)

[image]

Fyi this is the array that populates:

[{"balance":"0.00","item":"Lampada","id_item":"540"},{"balance":"0.00","item":"Taglio","id_item":"541"},{"balance":"1.00","item":"Piega","id_item":"542"},{"balance":"11.00","item":"Gelati","id_item":"543"}]

Thank you very much

Comment: did you try with the below answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the list is getting populated every time the API call is made. Means if the call is made 4 times then your list would be populated 4 times with the same data.

`mItemSubscriptionList.add(modelItemSubscription);` will not override but it will add the items no matter it the items are already present in the list.

Now what I suggest is you should clear your list before you make a call to API. Just add `mItemSubscriptionList.clear()` after `ApiMapper mapper = new ApiMapper();`

Comment: Hi, I did try but I got the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are populating your `Spinner` adapter so I will describe how it should be done with no code.

First everytime you fetch your data from you `API` you should clear your main `ArrayList` which holds the data and update the `Spinner`'s adapter:

```
adapter.notifySetDataChanged(); // Depending on the adapter
```

After that populate your `ArrayList` with the new fetched data and call

`adapter.notifySetDataChanged();`
 again so your data get refreshed.

Try this and tell if it works. If not, please add more code so we can see how you are populating your adapter after fetching the data.